# Best way to make an animtation for mobile, which you can pause and resume OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, mobile

I'm making an animated gramophone, which plays music and animates itself onclick, then stops when click again. What is the best way of doing this?

My first idea was making it a GIF, but that would make it hard to pause and start onclick events (I did find a script which uses html5 to draw a still frame from the GIF to take its place).

I could make it into an MP4 (h264) and using html5 video... then the pause and start are all built in, but this makes a larger file size and I do not know, will I run into any issues with mobile? I know a lot of background video isn't supported on mobile and that it falls back onto still pictures... am I wrong about this?

I could use Adobe Animate to export it as a javascript animation and use on an HTML5 canvas. Would this have compatibility issues? Can HTML5 canvas animations easily be paused and resumed?

Answer (score 2):

You can create sprite image (Image with all frames of your animation), than you can show parts of this image by manipulation with position and clipping of this image from js.

You may also create css entries for every frame as background, than in js just change class of some element periodically.

In that case you will have all control of your animation so you can slow it down, or pause as you wish.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you completely, do you have a link to any examples of what you mean?

I'm looking for a similar effect to this, which I can pause and play with a click event:

http://animationsa2z.com/attachments/Image/gramophones/Gramophone2.gif

Comment: Read this http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/ or this https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-spritesheet-animation--gamedev-13099    You will get the idea.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this was extremely helpful! This is the best way to do it I suppose eh?

I was kind of hoping that if I put the animation into Adobe Animate and export it as an HTML animation that there would just be a really easy way to call pause and start methods.

Comment: If I have a GIF with a million frames, is there an easy way to explode them them into one image all spaced evenly width-wise (using photoshop or any program)?

Comment: Any idea how you would make this mobile responsive using media queries? Would you use Javascript to detect the resize of the window?